# Trying to validate a contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a complete rails rookie and i'm trying to create validation for a contact form. I've started the validation code, but if i just load my contact page and click submit, it doesn't show any validation errors.

Here's the form in my view:

```
  <%= form_for :message, :id => 'contactForm', :url => { :action => "create" } do |f|-%>

        <%= label_tag 'name', 'Name:' %>
        <%= f.text_field 'name', :class =>'required requiredField' %> 

        <%= label_tag 'email', 'Email:' %>
        <%= f.email_field 'email', :class =>'required requiredField email' %>

        <%= label_tag 'message', 'Message:' %>
        <%= f.text_area 'message', :class => 'required requiredField', :rows => 20, :cols => 30 %>

        <%= f.submit :class => 'button' do -%>
            <a href="#" class="button" style="float:right;"><span>Submit</span></a>
        <% end %>
    <% end -%>
```

Controller:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

    layout "content"

    def index
        @activeLi = "contact"
    end

    def new
        @message = Message.new
    end

    def create
        @message = Message.new(params[:message])

        if @message.valid?
            # need to actually send the email message here
            flash[:notice] = "Message sent! We will get back to you shortly."
            redirect_to root_url
        else 
            render :action => 'new'
        end
    end

end
```

Model:

```
class Message

    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    extend ActiveModel::Naming

    attr_accessor :name, :email, :message

    validates_presence_of :name, :email, :message
    validates_length_of :message, :maximum => 4000

    def initialize(attributes={})
        attributes.each do |name, value|
            send("#{name}=", value)
        end
    end

    def persisted?
        false
    end
end
```

routes:

```
get "contact/index"
post "contact/create"
```

Comment: Should probably be form_for( :message... also what does your config/routes.rb look like.

Comment: I changed it to :message and added my routes.rb to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the post line in you routes.rb to

```
post 'contact/create'
get 'contact/new'
```

Comment: I've updated my routes and my form_for in my view and now I get this error `Missing template contact/new, application/new with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}.` Why would it not recognize this line in my ContactController `layout "content"`.

Comment: do you have the file `app/view/layouts/content.erb.html`? And that somewhere inside that file there is a call to `yield`?  Also you might need to restart the webserver when changing routes.rb.

Comment: I've tried restarting my server and yes I have a layouts/content.html.erb file with a call to yield.

Comment: This line was the killer `render :action => 'new'` since I wanted to show the same view.

Answer (score 2):

You're posting the form back to the :index action, but no where in the :index action are you trying to create and save and instance of ContactModel.  Until you do that, it will never validate.    You want to add something like this to your :index action:

if request.post?
  cm = ContactModel.new(...params go here...)
  if cm.save
    # all is fine
  else
    # spit out errors
  end
end

I would suggest not naming your model "ContactModel" (get rid of the 'Model').  ContactRequest, ContactSubmission, etc... something like that.

Also, check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr .  Very applicable to what you're doing.

And lastly, switch your form_tag to form_for and use a new instance of your model.  Keeps things nice and clean all the way around.

Comment: I took a look at that screencast as well as number 219. I've also updated my post with my latest code. It's still not showing any validation errors. Do I still need to have `if request.post?....` as you have told me? I didn't see that in either screencast. Also, do i need to put something in my view so the validation errors show up there?

Answer (score 1):

I am a rookie at Rails myself - have been learning it only for a month now. If I understand you right, you would like to show the errors when your form is submitted. I hope your model isnt getting saved to the db when submitted without the right values due to the validates_presence_of in your model. You probably need the following code in your form just below your form_for tag. Any validation errors would be shown then.

```
<% if @message.errors.any? %>
<h4>Errors</h4>
<ul>
    <% @message.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message%></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's not saving anything to the db because my model is not extending ActiveRecord. I tried your code but now it throws an error: `You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.errors`

Comment: @Catfish pls try my updated code..Looks like the activerecord in the view is nil. I had a capital M instead of lowercase m in message (your active record)